# Access path between parent and child table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have parent and child tables as shown below.

```
Child_table | Reference_colums | Parent_table | Referenced_columns
------------|------------------|--------------|-------------------
T1          | Clan_Id          | T0           | Clan_Id
X1          | Clan_Id          | T0           | Clan_Id
X2          | Clan_Id          | T0           | Clan_Id
T2          | Clan_Id          | T1           | Clan_Id
Y1          | Clan_Id          | T1           | Clan_Id
Y2          | Clan_Id          | X1           | Clan_Id
T3          | C31              | T2           | C2
T4          | C4               | T3           | C32
```

If I give input (Parent table = T0 an Child table as T4)
I should get output as

```
Child_table | Reference_colums | Parent_table | Referenced_columns
------------|------------------|--------------|-------------------
T1          | Clan_Id          | T0           | Clan_Id
T2          | Clan_Id          | T1           | Clan_Id
T3          | C31              | T2           | C2
T4          | C4               | T3           | C32
```

As access path between T4 and T0 is
T0 ->T1->T2->T3->T4

Can you please help me to write the SELECT query in Oracle

Comment: What role, if any, do the `REFERENCE_COLUMNS` and `REFERENCED_COLUMNS` columns play in the problem statement?

Comment: You need the `CONNECT BY` clause to make this work.

Comment: @DavidAldridge or a recursive Cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @DavidAldrige you need to use the Oracle's `CONNECT BY` that handles hierarchical queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
START WITH child = 'T4' 
CONNECT BY prior parent = child and child != 'T0';
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da13cf/2)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using Oracle's *connect by* clause. I have been trying to use Common Table Expressions (CTE) instead because they are not proprietary to Oracle. The skill translates to other databases, which in my case is SQL server. The following query will give you the results you desire, but using a CTE instead of *connect by*.

The **DATASET** clause is just setting up the sample data, **FINDSET** is where the work is performed:

```
WITH
    dataset
    AS
        (SELECT 'T1' AS child_table, 'T0' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'X1' AS child_table, 'T0' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'X2' AS child_table, 'T0' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'T2' AS child_table, 'T1' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y1' AS child_table, 'T1' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y2' AS child_table, 'X1' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'T3' AS child_table, 'T2' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'T4' AS child_table, 'T3' AS parent_table
           FROM DUAL),
    findset (parent_table, child_table)
    AS
        (SELECT parent_table, child_table
           FROM dataset
          WHERE child_table = 'T4'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dataset.parent_table, dataset.child_table
           FROM findset INNER JOIN dataset ON dataset.child_table = 
findset.parent_table)
    SELECT *
      FROM findset;
```

This gives the following result:

PARENT_TABLE CHILD_TABLE 
T3           T4
T2           T3
T1           T2
T0           T1